# Como usar dos arreglos como uno solo?

Tags: c++

Necesito su ayuda, estoy resolviendo un problema de c++ que trata sobre lo siguiente:

El directorio telefónico se encuentra en proceso de actualización. Para ello se ha decidido almacenar la información actual de todas las personas del directorio en dos arreglos: uno para los nombres y otro para los teléfonos y proceder a indagar casa por casa si los datos siguen siendo correctos. Usted ha decidido participar en el proceso de licitación para el proceso de actualización y para ello debe probar su capacidad de pensamiento algorítmico diseñando un programa que lea los arreglos de nombres y teléfonos y posteriormente solicite un nombre a buscar e indique el número telefónico registrado. Debe utilizar funciones para cada uno de estos procedimientos.

mi duda es como puedo yo unir estos dos arreglos y que me lea estos datos, o como podria solucionarlo, gracias

Comment: Es bueno que pongas lo que has intentado, podrias leer, investigar y tratar de hacer algo, si ahi tienes algun problema recurres a elaborar tu pregunta

Comment: La relación que mantiene los datos coherentes es que los datos comparten índices, es decir, `telefono[i]` te da el número del teléfono del abonado `abonado[i]`

Comment: Para usar dos arreglos como uno solo, simplemente crea dos arreglos y úsalos como si fueran uno.

Answer (score 0):

Para unir dos arreglos deberias usar una matriz (arreglo de dos dimenciones) donde el primero indice seria el nombre y el segundo seria los telefonos.

Seria algo como:

int matriz[10][10];

Completandolo con sus respectivos tamaños